# datepickerfield how to display upcoming years

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

```
        {
            xtype: 'datepickerfield',
            label: 'Start Date',
            name: 'startdate',
            value: new Date()
        },
```

I' m using this code to display a data picker for time. The picks show me a list of years from 1980 to 2012. I would need have limited number of year lets imagine from 2000 to 2015. how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the yearFrom and yearTo config options... I find its best to browse config options in the sencha touch 2 docs, usually find what im looking for rather quickly

Answer (score 1):

not forget that *yearFrom* and *yearTo* related to picker, not to field itself

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    label: 'Start Date',
    picker: {
        yearFrom: 2000,
        yearTo: 2015
    }
    name: 'startdate',
    value: new Date()
},
```

Relative to current year:

```
{
    xtype: 'datepickerfield',
    label: 'Start Date',
    picker: {
        yearFrom: new Date().getFullYear() - 1,
        yearTo: new Date().getFullYear() + 3
    }
    name: 'startdate',
    value: new Date()
},
```

Cheers, Oleg

Answer (score 1):

If you Use

```
       yearFrom: 2000,
       yearTo: 2015
```

if the YearTo is Expired you have Manually Upade after the year.

So better Use

```
      {

                                xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                                id:'date',
                                name:'date',
                                left:'5px',
                                left:'20px',
                                width: 280,
                                dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
                                value:{
                                          year:new Date().getFullYear(),
                                          month:new Date().getMonth()+1,
                                          day:new Date().getDate(),
                                     },
                                placeHolder:new Date(),
                                 picker:
                                {
                                    slotOrder: ['year', 'month', 'day'],
                                    value: new Date(),
                                    yearFrom:new Date().getFullYear(),
                                     yearTo: new Date().getFullYear() + 3
                                },





                    },
```